# Applying color in a Markdown file on GitHub

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Can I, in some way, color Markdown content?

I'm putting this in a gist on GitHub and was wondering if I could in some way color specific parts in my .md file. I’m pretty sure the .md file does support some HTML, but I’m not fully certain. If it does support coloring with HTML, how would that be done? If so, can I also change the font?

Comment: Markdown is effectively a superset of HTML, you can generally include arbitrary HTML (in this case e.g. `<span style="color: red">I am red</span>`).

Comment: Thanks that’ll work. (can’t figure how to accept I can’t see the button at all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you can include arbitrary HTML in your Markdown, but there's no guarantee that the renderer will honour it all. For example:

```
Hi here is some text <span style="color: red">this is red</span>.
```

renders on SO to:

> Hi here is some text this is red.

Although all of the text is included, the span gets stripped out entirely:

```html
<p>Hi here is some text this is red.</p>
```

Similarly, it looks like GitHub strips the styling out (it's [*"sanitized, aggressively"*](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup) - it leaves the span, at least, but removes the style attribute, see [Gist](https://gist.github.com/textbook/884bedbdf2ca929d9c05e41dc409fdf7)):

```html
<p>Hi here is some text <span>this is red</span>.</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Markdown doesn't support colouring even though it supports HTML. You can create red/green text using diff.

`````
````diff
+ Green Text
- Red Text
`````

You can also create coloured emojis using Unicode [Link](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)